# highlight code in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, syntax-highlighting

I know that there are many plugins that can make code highlight via javascript, but with it I have to find and escape text in tag 'code', it is not pretty solution for me.
Maybe there are any possible way to highlight source code that is wrapped in tag 'code' via java, or maybe spring mvc already have any solution for it?

Comment: What's hard or unpretty in `<pre><c:out value="${theJavaScriptCode}"/></pre>`? That's all you need to escape the text.

Comment: but if I have comments where users write text and some parts of it is <code></code> I have to find this parts of comment and unescape it without tag <code></code>, it is unpretty for me.

Comment: No, you don't. `c:out` will escape `<code></code>` to `&lt;code&gt;&lt;/code&gt;`, which will thus be rendered by the browser as `<code></code>`, literally. That's the principle of HTML escaping.

Comment: You do not understand me, let me give you one example:

if we have comment like it:
Trololo trololo ...
<code>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
....
</code>

Than I want to see beautiful text and code, but only text in tag code must be highlighted, it is main problem.

Comment: Ah, OK. So you want to be able to parse some user-entered text, detect <code> sections inside it, and highlight it. Why don't you do what this web app does, and use the Markdown syntax for comments?

Comment: 'Comments' - it is example. Users have to be able create big articles where will be big parts of code, code highlight must be there.

Comment: But you HAVE to decide on a format. If it's HTML, then they will have to provide valid HTML, and you have nothing to do. If it's Markdown, then it has to be valid markdown, and the markdown processor will change it to HTML. It can't be random text not obeying any rule.

Comment: Yes, I think your advice to use markdown will be pretty solution, thank you very much.